# Redirect 301 - Why adding question mark?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

In the .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /john-biography.php /about
```

When I type domain.com/john-biography.php in the browser, it become:

domain.com/about?/john-biography.php

Is that normal or what can be done to prevent that?

Comment: Do you use anything else like mod_rewrite?

Comment: Than it seems that an already internally rewritten URL is getting redirected externally. You should use mod_rewrite only in this case.

Comment: Could you provide example how mod_rewrite can be done in this case? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is typically for a conflict between mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite where a URL is redirected externally that was already rewritten internally by mod_rewrite.

In that case you should not use mod_alias but mod_rewrite only. So just convert your directive into a mod_rewrite equivalent:

```
RewriteRule ^john-biography\.php$ /about [L,R=301]
```

Put this in front of your other rules that rewrite internally.

Comment: Thank you, that seem to work fine :) Can that be done too? http://www.mydomain.co.uk/news/090/the-news-title-here become http://www.mydomain.co.uk/news/90/the-news-title-here (Notice the News ID)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apache manual for mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
The new URL should be an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and hostname.
```

So try:

```
Redirect 301 /john-biography.php http://www.yourdomain.com/about
```